# JOOQ getting an auto generated column value upon inserting it using the record, not returning

Tags: java, sql, jooq

JOOQ offers the very nice ability to do the following:

```
TableRecord tableRecord = dsl.newRecord(TABLE);
tableRecord.setSomeParam(...);
tableRecord.insert();
```

At this point the record should be inserted in the table.

We can do something like:

```
tableRecord.getSomeParam(); // will return value above
```

However, this:

```
tableRecord.getId(); // NULL
```

Always returns `null`. Is this by design? Do we have to use `returning(TABLE.ID)` to get the autogenerated ID value instead of the `Record`? Is this behaviour different if the query is executed in a transactional context?

---

Edit:

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.10, and my table definition is similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,       
    name character varying(245),
    some_uuid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    CONSTRAINT item_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT item_item_uuid_key UNIQUE (item_uuid)
)
```

Additional information:

- PostgreSQL driver: "postgresql:postgresql>9.1-901.jdbc4"
- JOOQ version: `3.8.6`

Comment: 1) what database are you using? 2) what's the DDL for your table?

Comment: Hello Mr. Eder: I've just updated the question with answers to your questions. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Interesting. This should work out of the box, but I cannot reproduce it this way... What jOOQ version are you using? What JDBC driver and version? Have you debugged through jOOQ to see if jOOQ takes some wrong turn at some place?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that you cannot reproduce the wrong behaviour in the question description? I have updated the ticket description with the version numbers. I also have not tried debugging through the library yet - I will try to do so as soon as possible. Thank you for the responses so far!

Comment: Indeed, I cannot reproduce the wrong behaviour in the question description. I'm getting that ID value on my side. Anyway, have you considered upgrading your 6 year old PostgreSQL driver?

Comment: @LukasEder can you confirm that when inserting/storing a record in a SQLite database, the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not fetched back to the record object ?

Comment: @facewindu: Please ask a new question with details.

Comment: @LukasEder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217820/jooq-not-returning-primary-key-after-store-on-sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `store()` method (https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.2.0/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#store())

Autogenerated ID will be refreshed after storing record.

You could also call `record.refresh()` after `insert`, then your record will contain refreshed values.